# How can I split a string along each letter

Tags: python, string, split

I have a string and i want it each of the letter to become separated by a a space. e.g `"abc"` becomes `"a b c"`

I tried using `.split()` but i don't know what to put as the separator

my current codes looks somthing like:

```
x = "abc"

print(" ".join(x.split()))
```

I know how I could do this using iteration but I would rather have it more compact.

Comment: `print(*"abc")` or `print(' '.join("abc"))`

Comment: Pass it directly into `' '.join` with `' '.join(x)`.

Answer (score 4):

[`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) takes an *iterable* as its argument. A string is an iterable in Python. Meaning you can just pass it to `join()`, like this:

```
x = "abc"
print(' '.join(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

- Make a list of letters
- Join them together between spaces

```
lst = list("abc")
joined = ' '.join(lst)

print(joined) # "a b c"
```

Hopefully this works for you :)

Comment: A string is an iterable of letters, you don't need to convert it into a list.

Comment: yeah forgot that...